# how to remove the navigation bar from jenkins pages?

Tags: jenkins

I need embed jenkins page to my website, can somebody point me how to remove the jenkins navigation bar, both with headers and side menu.
or can give me other solution ?
thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use CSS properties like

.Header{
Display:none 
}

And do same for the footer

Comment: you mean use the 'the simple theme' plugin and inject the css pre-defined with display: none attribute ? sounds like a good idea !

Comment: Just inspect the Jenkins dashboard about what they call there header and footer and inject custom css let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: after I inject below css code it works, thanks varnit !                                


`div#page-head {
    display: none;
}
body.two-column #side-panel {
    display: none;
}
body.two-column #main-panel {
 border: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
div#page-body {
 border: 0px;
}
footer {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Thanks for marking it as solved can you up vote the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

You can choose plugin as [beautiful Jenkins dashboard](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/01/10/beautiful-jenkins-dashboard/).